# How to get the difference between 2 times in android

Tags: java, android, calendar

I want to find difference between current system time and inserted data&time `String`. I have tried this:

```
 try {

            String strFileDate = "2012-04-19 15:15:00";
            DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
            Date date = formatter2.parse(strFileDate);
            long difference = date.getTime() - System.currentTimeMillis();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(difference);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    formatter2.format(calendar.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but it does not give me the right result. Am I doing it right?

### **Update**

I tried following ::

```
String strFileDate = "2012-04-19 15:15:00";
            DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
            Date date = formatter2.parse(strFileDate);
            long diffInMs = date.getTime()
                    - new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime();

            long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMs);

            long hour = diffInSec / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            double minutes = diffInSec / (1000 * 60);
            // long diffInHour = TimeUnit.to(diffInMs);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "left time is :: " + hour + ":" + minutes,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**output::** 
**left time is:: -2 : -131.0**

### **UPdate(20/4/2012)**

```
try {
            Date dt = new Date();
            String strFileDate = "2012-04-20 13:10:00";
            DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
            Date date = formatter2.parse(strFileDate);
            String s = getTimeDiff(dt, date);
            Log.i("Date is :: >>> ", s);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 public String getTimeDiff(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo) {
        String diff = "";
        long timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
        diff = String.format("%d hour(s) %d min(s)", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff)));
        return diff;
```

}

**Output::**
04-20 12:48:06.629: 
INFO/Date is :: >>>(1295): 2183 hour(s) 38 min(s)

Comment: i want time differance in minut and hour..

Comment: What is not working? What are you expecting to see in the Toast? What do you expect from this snippet? Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(difference);  Please give more details.

Comment: Checkout this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635935/how-can-i-calculate-a-time-span-in-java-and-format-the-output

Comment: @krishnakumarp i have update my code please check it

Comment: you should replace long diffInMs = date.getTime() - new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime(); with long diffInMs = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime() - date.getTime();

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JodaTime for calculating period(Time Difference). http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Then use the simple calculation. If you want the difference in day, month, year, minute, second then you need JodaTime.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5):

```
String strFileDate = "2012-04-19 15:15:00";
DateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date date = formatter2.parse(strFileDate);
long diffInMs = date.getTime() - new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime();


long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diffInMis);

long diffInHour = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diffInMis);
```

use TimeUnit to get the number of seconds.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Edited:

Get [TIMEUNIT Code here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.java/?v=source&disposition=attachment)

```
public String getTimeDiff(Date dateOne, Date dateTwo) {
        String diff = "";
        long timeDiff = Math.abs(dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime());
        diff = String.format("%d hour(s) %d min(s)", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(timeDiff)));
        return diff;
}
```

Comment: can you give entire example??

Comment: i have contine with `diffInMs` so now tell me how can i convert long into minuts

Comment: @hotveryspicy there are not `TimeUnit.toMinutes(diff); ` any type of method

Comment: create object then try TimeUnit mTimeUnit= new TimeUnit(); mTimeUnit.toMinutes(diff);

Comment: see my edited answer and download new source code of *Timeunit*, android inbuilt class isnt having full function.

Comment: it not get me proper output can you tell me what happen over there ??/

Comment: what you getting as an output?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date.getYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDay(),date.getHourOFday(),date.getMinutes(),date.getSeconds); // not syntactically right..
long difference = System.currentTimeMillis()-calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

and for getting difference in hour

```
double hour = difference/(1000*60*60);
double minutes = difference/(1000*60);
```

Comment: hour get me proper but minuts not get me proper

Comment: @user1343673 .. see updated answer.. i have changed **long difference = System.currentTimeMillis()-calendar.getTimeInMillis();**

Answer (score 0):

- What output do you get?
- What output do you expect?

See [#3960661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960661/android-difference-between-two-dates-in-seconds) if you need this time in seconds.

Comment: Then look at [#6118922](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118922/convert-seconds-value-to-hours-minutes-seconds-android-java) :)

Comment: @PareshMayani .. is there something you even tolerate.. why do you make fun of people who ask amature questions... i bet if you had spent the same amount of time answering someone's question it would have helped them,.. rather than trying to be funny here.. 2nd time same **BMW** comment.. what a shame...

Comment: @sandy FYI, At this point of time, there are lot many questions/answers already available here for the topic "Date/time difference". And he directly saying in "order" like language that i want this, this.

Comment: @PareshMayani .. why don't you paste a link then... why do you always crack jokes... it discourages anyone from asking question..

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(
    LocalDateTime.parse( "2012-04-19 15:15:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ,
    LocalDateTime.parse( "2012-04-19 23:49:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) 
)
```

> 514

## Time zone

Your code ignores the crucial issue of time zone.

The `java.util.Date` class represents a moment in UTC. Meanwhile, your input string "2012-04-19 15:15:00" lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. You must explicitly place that value into the context of an expected/desired zone/offset or else those legacy classes will apply a zone/offset implicitly.

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Your input nearly complies with standard ISO 8601 formatting. Switch that SPACE in the middle for a `T`.

```
String input = "2012-04-19 15:15:00".replace( " " , "T" ) ;  // Convert to ISO 8601 format.
```

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` object, as your input lacks a zone or offset.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Apply the zone or offset that you know for certain was intended for that input.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ; // Or some other offset.
```

…or…

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

If you want the delta between two moments as a span of time unattached to the timeline scaled as hours-minutes-seconds, calculate a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

Similar, but scaled in years-months-days, use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Period.html). Extract `LocalDate` date-only objects to feed the factory method of `Period`.

```
Period p = Period.between( start.toLocalDate() , stop.toLocalDate() ) ;
```

### Total elapsed

If you want a single number of total elapsed minutes, seconds, etc., use `ChronoUnit::between` method on the `ChronoUnit` enum.

```
long totalMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between( start , stop ) ;  // Calculate total number of minutes in entire span of time.
```

### Generating strings

Generate a string in [standard ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). Just call `Duration::toString` or `Period::toString`.

The format is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks the beginning, and `T` separates any years-months-days from any hours-minutes-seconds.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

You can interrogate for the parts by calling various getter methods.

**Tip:** If you work with such spans of time much at all, add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project to use the `Interval` and `LocalDateRange` classes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).